# How do i generate a sequence number for each 10 rows a number in sql server

Tags: sql-server

In select i need a sequence number for every 10 rows a number

for first 10 rows1, for 11 to 20 rows 2, 21 to 30 rows 3 like...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please explain your question clearly by providing sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
WITH cte
     AS (SELECT 1 id
         UNION ALL
         SELECT id + 1
         FROM   cte
         WHERE  id < 20)
SELECT ( Row_number()
           OVER(
             ORDER BY id) - 1 ) / 10 + 1 AS seq,
       id
FROM   cte
```

But this will create numbers only by order of some Column not as in table.

Comment: thanks for the replay, not by any dependancy of column names

Comment: yeah, its depending on id, but in my case its not like that, independent generation in select sql query

Comment: @user3459969 I don't think it is possible in TSQL. With out any order y u need a sequence!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 'someTable' as your table, and without any assumptions as to a column with a sequential id, the following would work by numbering rows and then categorizing every 10 rows:

```
WITH someTable as
(
    SELECT top 100 o1.* FROM sys.objects o1 cross join sys.objects o2
),
numberedTable AS
(
    SELECT someTable.name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY object_id) AS rowNum
    FROM someTable
)
SELECT name, rowNum, CAST(rowNum / 10 AS INT) + 1 AS sequence10Items
FROM numberedTable;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/22529)

Comment: Thanks for the replay, without dependency of table columns

Comment: If you mean something truly generic, which you can then apply to any sql select, you would have to use dynamic sql. This probably indicates you should be doing the grouping of 10 in code instead - this should easy to do with a `DataReader` or `IEnumerable`